# when i use the gsutil in c# (diagnostics.process, cmd), it's does not end

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to automate using gsutil in c #. 
I use the "gsutil cp" command . If the file is small , the copied successfully . However, the file size is more than 10MB, the command is not end . I 've waited a long time , the command does not end .

This is my code.

```
          String currentUser = Environment.UserName;

            if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\" + currentUser + @"\" + botoFileName) == false)
            {
                log.Error("can't find the confileFileName (" + botoFileName + ")");
                return false;
            }

            log.Info("==========================================================");
            log.Info("fileKey = " + fileKey);

            string resultPro = null;
            string resultError = null;

            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            System.Diagnostics.Process pro = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            proInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "cmd.exe");
            proInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            proInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            pro.StartInfo = proInfo;
            pro.Start();

            pro.StandardInput.Write("c:" + Environment.NewLine);
            pro.StandardInput.Write(@"set BOTO_PATH=C:\Users\" + currentUser + @"\" + botoFileName + Environment.NewLine);

            if (usingCloudSdk.Equals("true"))
            {
                //when using google sdk and python
                pro.StandardInput.Write(@"gsutil cp " + fileKey + " " + gcsPath + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else
            {
                //when using only gsutil and python
                pro.StandardInput.Write(@"cd C:\gsutil\gsutil" + Environment.NewLine);
                pro.StandardInput.Write(@"python gsutil -m cp " + fileKey + " " + gcsPath + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            pro.StandardInput.Close();

            resultPro = pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            resultError = pro.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            pro.WaitForExit();
            pro.Close();

            log.Info(resultPro);
            log.Info(resultError);
            log.Info("==========================================================");

            if (resultError.IndexOf("Exception") != -1 || resultError.IndexOf("Fail") != -1)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
```

please help me.

Comment: Can you capture the interim stdout/stderr of the gsutil command to get an idea of where it is hanging?  If you do this, I'd also recommend running with the debug flag enabled: `python gsutil -D -M cp ...`

Comment: When i upload a log(50KB) to GCS, It's ok. but when i upload a log (30MB), it don't finish. i want show the failed debug message, but it don't finish after "resultPro = pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();" line.

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx - I'm suggesting that you use something like BeginOutputReadLine, as stream filling up may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: wow, you're right. i was add the line "process.BeginOutputReadLine();" before ReadToEnd(). and it wasn't deadlock. i test it up to 2GB logfile to copy. I am very grateful to you.

Comment: Hi olivia, Can you please post the working code? Need to the refer it.